# AbstractMethodError: This method must be defined in the concrete class type

Tags: class, types, concrete, abstractmethoderror

df= df.drop(Karoo_output_2016_dry[df.Month == 1].index)

Can someone help me what is wrong?

Yesterday I used it and today it is giving this error.